# How to send data from Arduino pro mini to android

Tags: android, bluetooth, arduino

I want a way to send data (string or int) from arduino  to an android device.
Is there a code for arduino that can send data from Bluetooth module (hc06)  and an android app that can show the data received ?
I tried doing that but I got rubbish data (question marks)

Comment: i cant its too long.

Comment: can u please write a code that can send an int from an arduino pro mini to an android app

Comment: you can check these blogs [Bog 1](https://bellcode.wordpress.com/2012/01/02/android-and-arduino-bluetooth-communication/) [Blog 2](http://www.allaboutcircuits.com/projects/communicate-with-your-arduino-through-android/)